# Saving image form Clipboard

Tags: c#, image, windows-runtime, save, clipboard

i want to save one Image inside clipboard in winrt to file. but i found no way. can you help please?

```
var dataPackage = Clipboard.GetContent();
            var t = await dataPackage.GetBitmapAsync();
            var t2 = await t.OpenReadAsync();
            t2.AsStream();
            t2.Seek(0);
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.SetSource(t2);
            Image image = new Image();
            image.Source = bitmapImage;<
```

Comment: What is the problem?  Does this error?

Comment: no error. but i don´t know how i can save it to file.

Comment: You have an `Image` object...so:  `image.Save("C:\\myDir\\myFile.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);`

Comment: Image.save is not aviable in Windows.ui.controls.image at Windows RT

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped you. It will also help to other developers who could face such problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go :)

Please note you can't use ANY folder to save. I have passed `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path` as desination. You can use `FolderPicker` and then pass the path of picked folder.

```
private async Task StoreImageFromClipboardAsync()
{
    var dataPackage = Clipboard.GetContent();
    var formats = dataPackage.AvailableFormats;
    if (formats.Contains("Bitmap"))
    {
        var t = await dataPackage.GetBitmapAsync();
        var file = await ChangeIRASRToStorageFileAsync(t, ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Clipboard.png");
    }
}

private async Task<StorageFile> ChangeIRASRToStorageFileAsync(IRandomAccessStreamReference MyIRASR, String StorageFolderPath, String StorageFileName)
{
    IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType MyIRASWCT = await MyIRASR.OpenReadAsync();
    StorageFolder MyStorageFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(StorageFolderPath);
    StorageFile MyStorageFile = await MyStorageFolder.CreateFileAsync(StorageFileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer MyBuffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(Convert.ToUInt32(MyIRASWCT.Size));
    IBuffer iBuf = await MyIRASWCT.ReadAsync(MyBuffer, MyBuffer.Capacity, InputStreamOptions.None);
    await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(MyStorageFile, iBuf);
    return MyStorageFile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that, just added the last line to your existing code (e.g. for PNG)

```
var dataPackage = Clipboard.GetContent();
            var t = await dataPackage.GetBitmapAsync();
            var t2 = await t.OpenReadAsync();
            t2.AsStream();
            t2.Seek(0);
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.SetSource(t2);
            Image image = new Image();
            image.Source = bitmapImage;
            image.Save("ImagePathToStore.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.PNG);
```

[Link for Supported imageformates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.aspx)

Comment: Image.save is not aviable in Windows.ui.controls.image at Windows RT.

Comment: `image.Save` is not the part of WinRT APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Last post example saves an BMP image instead of a PNG image. The following solution works for me if I want to save PNG files from Clipboard:

```
private async Task StoreImageFromClipboardAsync()
{
  var dataPackage = Clipboard.GetContent();
  if (datapackage.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Bitmap))
  {
    var t = await dataPackage.GetBitmapAsync();
    var file = await SaveToPngTaskFile(t, ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, 
      "Clipboard.png");
  }
}

public static async Task<StorageFile> SaveToPngTaskFile
  (IRandomAccessStreamReference rndAccessStreamReference, 
   StorageFolder storageFolder, String storageFileName)
{
  IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType rndAccessStreamWithContentType = 
    await rndAccessStreamReference.OpenReadAsync();
  StorageFile storageFile = 
    await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(storageFileName, 
      CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
  var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(rndAccessStreamWithContentType);
  var pixels = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
  var outStream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
  var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, outStream);
  encoder.SetPixelData(decoder.BitmapPixelFormat, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
    decoder.OrientedPixelWidth, decoder.OrientedPixelHeight,
    decoder.DpiX, decoder.DpiY,
    pixels.DetachPixelData());
  await encoder.FlushAsync();
  outStream.Dispose();
  return storageFile;
}
```