# C# saves a captured photo

Tags: c#, io

I am trying to save an captured photo into a folder as following:

```
        CameraCaptureUI captureUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
        captureUI.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
        captureUI.PhotoSettings.CroppedSizeInPixels = new Size(200, 200);

        StorageFile photo = await 
        captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);

        if (photo == null)
        {
            // User cancelled photo capture
            return;
        }
        StorageFolder destinationFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("ProfilePhotoFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        await photo.CopyAsync(destinationFolder, "ProfilePhoto.jpg", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await photo.DeleteAsync();
```

However, I cannot find the ProfilePhotoFolder in my file system. Could any one please tell me where is this folder. This is an Universal Windows project.

Comment: You could put in a breakpoint and find out using the debugger.

Comment: My guess is that by "Captured"  it is on the clipboard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965776/saving-image-form-clipboard

Comment: @Sorceri I just updated my code. I am using the webcam to capture a photo.

Comment: @I found it under User/AppData/Local/Packages and randomly named folder. Is there a way to keep the image somewhere more permanent?

Comment: @hatchet I found it under User/AppData/Local/Packages and randomly named folder. Is there a way to keep the image somewhere more permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write to UWP LocalFolders the data is placed into Isolated Storage which is only accessible by your application, and thus you won't simply be able to fire up Windows Explorer and start digging into the files.

The recommended way for Windows 10 devices is to set your device to Developer Mode then use the web browser interface they've created (see https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/06/08/using-the-app-file-explorer-to-see-your-app-data/#6O50PWljxSKfKCAm.97).

Comment: I did find the photo, but I am trying to keep it somewhere more permanent.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
```

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.knownfolders)

Comment: There is an access denied exception